# how to see bitcoin blockchain and addressess for testnet

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, blockchain.info, testnet

in my site the user has a link to check the transactions and his wallet address.

right now I am using this:

blockchain: https://blockchain.info/tx/#{txid}

address_url: https://blockchain.info/address/#{address}

and works perfect for btc mainnet

in my code I have this to get the blocks and addresses info, my question is how can I get the same thing but using testnet?

I tried https://www.blockcypher.com api but did not work, any help? thank you.

what I want it is get the transactions and addressess info from their in my website.

it is already working but just with btc main chain

I am using testnetchain already: bitcoin.conf testnet=1

can someone one explain how to get this info using the testnet?

is blockcypher or another website similar to blockchaininfo to me get these parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blockchain.info does appear to support testnet blocks and transactions by simply using the "testnet" subdomain.

For example:

txid: [`4200cea53a075f3081156a9d664fe05cfe108a09e26e8f20ee65e7ebe141060b`](https://testnet.blockchain.info/tx/4200cea53a075f3081156a9d664fe05cfe108a09e26e8f20ee65e7ebe141060b)

block: [`1443900`](https://testnet.blockchain.info/block-index/5444073)

address: [`mum6KQEwAHGDRr7HRXx7hufcsyqiGPUCtN`](https://testnet.blockchain.info/address/mum6KQEwAHGDRr7HRXx7hufcsyqiGPUCtN)

So in your case simply use this:

https://testnet.blockchain.info/tx/#{txid}

https://testnet.blockchain.info/address/#{address}